# How can I print the value based on conditions on pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas dataframe and python.
Currently, I have a pandas dataframe which I'd like to print the values based on conditions set.

My df looks like this:

```
ID     Name    Price
1      Apple     1
2      Orange    0.5
3      Pear      0.7
```

I'd like to code it such that when I ask the user to input the ID, it will return the price. For example, if the user input 2, it should return 0.5.

```
inputid = input("Please input ID: ")
```

What should I do next to get return Price from df based on the input?

Comment: try this, ```df.loc[df.ID.eq(int(inputid)), 'Price'].values[0]```

Comment: Please accept an answer and consider upvoting other which has helped u solve your problem. This way it helps the community and stackoverflow to keep good answers in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

1. Set *ID* column in *df* as its index:

   ```
    df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
   ```
2. Define the following function:

   ```
    def getPrice():
        inputid = input("Please input ID: ")
        try:
            return df.loc[int(inputid), 'Price']
        except:
            return 'No such ID'
   ```

Then when you call it, executing `getPrice()`:

- An input prompt is displayed.
- The user enters the ID.
- Within *try* block this function attempts to:

  - convert *inputid* to *int* (the index contains *int* values,
    but *inputid* is a *string*), so one cause of error can be that
    the user just pressed *Enter* without entering any value,
  - even if the user entered a number, it is possible that *df*
    does not contain such *ID* (the second cause of error).
- If everything so far is OK, the function returns the price of interest.
- But if any error occurred, the result is an error message.

Comment: Thanks! i've managed to do it, but my results show with `Name: Price, dtype: float64`
Is there anyway to remove it? I'd just like the final result only.

Comment: I checked my code again and I the result is just a single *float*,
without any "additions".
Maybe you have some outdated version of *Pandas* (I have *1.0*).
Check also whether you executed *df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)* before.
From your output I see that your result is a *Series*, not a *float*.

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas documentation is very good and will cover everything you need.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Let's call your DataFrame `price_df`, depending on whether your ID column is set as the index of the dataframe or not.

If it is:

```py
print(price_df.loc[inputid, "Price"])
```

If it isn't:

```py
print(price_df[price_df["ID"] == inputid]["Price"])
```

The `.loc` method is the primary way of accessing data from a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : (1, 2,3),
                  'Name':('Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'),
                  'Price': (1, 0.5, 0.7)})
df
    ID  Name    Price
0   1   Apple   1.0
1   2   Orange  0.5
2   3   Pear    0.7

userin = input("Please input ID: ")
userin
`1`

df.loc[df['ID'] == float(userin)]

    ID  Name    Price
0   1   Apple   1.0
```

You need to change the user input to `float` or `int` for pandas to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`userin = input("input ID: ")`

`print("The price for the ID is-  ",df[df.ID==float(userin)].Price.values[0])`